# What is the easiest way to arrange string Month rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with a month column which is string:

```
Month      Value     Details
January      10        H12
April        12        J11
June         13        K03
May          08        Y21
```

I need to arrange the month in from `April to March` model. Which is the easiest way to do this?
Desired result:

```
Month      Value     Details
April        12        J11
May          08        Y21
June         13        K03
January      10        H12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need solution which working correctly if missing some months and all months in list of dictionary use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) and then change order by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
d = {'April':1,'May':2,'June':3,'July':4,'January':12}

df = df.iloc[df['Month'].map(d).argsort()]
print (df)
     Month  Value Details
1    April     12     J11
3      May      8     Y21
2     June     13     K03
0  January     10     H12
```

Or use [ordered categoricals](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html):

```
#add another months
c = ['April','May','June','July','January']
df['Month'] = pd.Categorical(df['Month'], categories=c, ordered=True)

df = df.sort_values('Month')
print (df)
     Month  Value Details
1    April     12     J11
3      May      8     Y21
2     June     13     K03
0  January     10     H12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
In [2048]: new_order = ['April','May','June','January']

In [2051]: df.set_index('Month', inplace=True)

In [2071]: df.loc[new_order].reset_index()    
Out[2071]: 
     Month  Value Details
0    April     12     J11
1      May      8     Y21
2     June     13     K03
3  January     10     H12
```

**OR**

```
In [2051]: df.reindex(new_order, axis=0).reset_index() 
Out[2071]: 
         Month  Value Details
    0    April     12     J11
    1      May      8     Y21
    2     June     13     K03
    3  January     10     H12
```